Could not load file or assembly despite dll and dependencies being present
I'm developing a Visual Studio Extension in .net Framework. I'm getting this ulcer-inducing error at runtime:

The xaml that calls it:

I've downloaded the most recent version of Syncfusion.Edit.WPF via NuGet and this also downloads its dependencies (listed here). It's clearly in the Project references:

The build directory also contains the right files:

Lastly, I used this in another Extension project with exactly the same libraries/references and it works fine. So I think it's something to do with my Solution/Project or a .net idiosyncracy.
I've tried all the normal: deleting obj/bin folder, cleaning the solution, restarting VS. It persists. Any ideas?
Github Repo here

Use SysInternals' Process Monitor to see where it looks for the .dll
